# PDP-11 Program to Execute Only in the Registers

Tags: pdp-11, registers

The contents of processor registers of a PDP-11/05, etc were available at UNIBUS memory addresses and it was possible to execute a small test program just in the processor registers without accessing any main memory i.e. not in core or MOS memory modules.

Is there an online reference or can somebody provide that code here?

Comment: Do you mean that the program itself was stored in registers? Does the test program have to do anything useful? For example `bra -2` is a short program that fits into one register.

Comment: `bra` is not a PDP-11 instruction. `br` ?

Comment: What do you want for an online reference?  On the 11/05 and 11/10 (only), the registers are in the address space for both console and CPU. Therefore you can toggle in instructions and presumably execute them (as long as PC logic knows to increment by 1 for these addresses).  I have never seen any claim that this was useful; you've got at most 7 registers available, including any you need as registers. So I wouldn't expect the capability to be well-documented.

Comment: In the 1970s while performing hardware maintenance on PDP-11 systems I used a DEC supplied program as a simple test of a processor. I don't remember if the program also performed a simple memory exercise.

Comment: That was probably [xxdp](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/xxdp/), also known as maindec.

Comment: Don't know about PDP-11 but it [worked on the -10s](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16277/332) (which also had more registers).

Comment: @davidbak - Sure, but the -10 ISA expressly put the ACs in the memory address space (AC #n = address n), and indeed the ACs might be in main memory if you were too cheap to buy the 'fast registers' option (maybe only on the KA10). On the -11, the registers are in their own address space, and it would be nutty to write code to access them through memory address space (in CPUs where that is possible) since that adds two bytes and one memory cycle to each instruction.

Comment: "and it would be nutty to ..." - as if _that's_ ever stopped anyone ...

Comment: @PDP11 - you assert that it is possible to **execute** out of 'register space' via their IO page addresses.  I haven't found even that mentioned in 11/05 manuals. Do you have a reference? (Or experience)

Comment: This pattern was used on the pdp-10 for such things as the RIM10B loader. https://www.inwap.com/pdp10/rim10b.html

Comment: I have experience, unfortunately no references. I doubt most DEC manuals except the KD-11B manual would even hint at the possibility of executing code out of the registers. Regarding the execution of code the KD-11B manual states:
To the program executed by the processor, the internal registers are indistinguishable from peripheral or memory registers. However, access to the internal registers is not available to devices attached to the Unibus other than the processor.

Comment: The KD-11B Processor Manual, Page 5-3 includes:-
An example of a simple program that loops on two SP register locations is as
follows:
Address           Instruction     Octal

Comment: 177700 (RO)    NOP               000240

Comment: 177701 (R1)     BR.-1 *           000777

Comment: Note that the `*` is not part of the instruction syntax; it's a reference to a footnote.  Also, the manual is a bit erratic about how to write `BR .-1`.   Conventionally there's a space  or tab after the operation mnemonic, and I've always supposed it to be required.

Comment: @another-dave the Macro-11 reference page I found on the Internet used bra. Shoot me.

Comment: There is a version of the MACRO-11 Reference Manual at http://www.bitsavers.org/www.computer.museum.uq.edu.au/RSX/AA-V027A-TC%20PDP-11%20MACRO-11%20Language%20Reference%20Manual.pdf

The Appendix C at C-1 lists the permanent Symbol Table, the Branch instruction is just BR

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the **PDP-11/05,11/10 computer manual** ([DEC-11-H05AA-B-D](http://www.bitsavers.org/www.computer.museum.uq.edu.au/pdf/DEC-11-H05AA-B-D%20PDP-11-05,%2011-10%20Computer%20Manual.pdf), section 10.5, page 10-3) DEC describes how the PDP-11/05 can execute short programs out of ***scratch pad memory*** (*SPM* or simply *SP*).  Scratch pad memory is DEC's term for a small section of static RAM used to store the PDP-11 registers and other internal processor state.

The manual goes on to give a two instruction program that can be used to validate the basic operation of the processor:

> **Address**            **Instruction**    **Octal**
> 177700(R0)       NOP                000240
> 177701(R1)       BR.-1*             000777

As noted in the text, the code is specially constructed to accommodate the unique behavior of the PC register when executing out of scratch pad memory:

> When executing a program from the SP, the PC (R7) is incremented by one; however, BR instructions always modify the PC by multiples of two.  Consequently, a BR instruction must be carefully used in a [SP] program to prevent the PC from being modified to an incorrect address.

In addition to validating the operation of the CPU, executing programs out of SPM can be quite useful for diagnosing memory issues, as it avoids the need to fetch instructions from potentially faulty memory.  On my own PDP-11/05, I use the following programs (written by me but possibly invented by others as well), to repeatedly read or write a single memory location:

**Continuously read a memory location**
(Start execution at 177702)

```
177700 (R0) XXXXXX  # Address of memory location to read
177701 (R1)         # Scratch location
177702 (R2) 011001  # mov (R0),R1
177703 (R3) 000777  # BR .-1
```

**Continuously write a memory location**
(Start execution at 177702)

```
177700 (R0) XXXXXX  # Address of memory location to write
177701 (R1) YYYYYY  # Value to be written
177702 (R2) 010110  # mov R1,(R0)
177703 (R3) 000777  # BR .-1
```

*EDIT:*

Following up with a bit of related information: According to the **PDP-11 UNIBUS Processor Handbook** ([link](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/handbooks/PDP-11_UNIBUS_Processor_Handbook_1985.pdf), Appendix A, page A-14), the PDP-11/05, 11/10 is the only PDP-11 model that can execute a program out of its general purpose registers.

Comment: Good reference, thanks. I went looking for such, but failed to find it.

Comment: Presumably your `BR -1` should be `BR .-1` ?

Comment: @another-dave: Indeed! I guess that was just my form of pidgin PDP-11 assembly. :)

Comment: This is the answer. Also found a reference in the KD-11B Processor Maintenance Manual (DEC-11-HKD88-A-D), Page 5-3 which is available for download from bitsavers.org at http://www.bitsavers.org/www.computer.museum.uq.edu.au/pdf/DEC-11-HKDBB-A-D%20KD11-B%20Processor%20Maintenance%20Manual.pdf This included the address range for the SPM which was larger than just the processor register space (R0 - R7). A warning that some addresses in the SPM should not be used as they were required for execution of the microprogram.

Comment: Re the latest edit... I never knew the PDP-11/05 was the only processor that could execute from the General Purpose Registers. I had only ever used this facility when there was a core memory problem. Then it was not possible to execute programs. Later generation systems such as the PDP-11/04, PDP-11/34A, etc., used the more reliable semiconductors so I never needed to execute code in the GPRs.